# Edit post without any change

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, edits

I click to edit a post and without making any change I clicked `Save` instead of `cancel` by mistake and it accepted.

Now it is showing my name in [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20486526/revisions) list with no changes.

> [image: edit]

and as hims056 pointed [time-line of post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20486526/timeline) also indicate I have not revised it.

Comment: yeah, it won't show any thing in your activity tab too.

Comment: Also [the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20486526/timeline) doesn't indicate that you have revised.

Comment: surely "no change" saves should be ignored. in fact, I would vote for ignoring "trivial" changes too, such as removal/addition of blank final lines, trailing whitespace at end of lines, etc

Comment: When did you open the question for editing? Was it within 8 seconds of clicking "Save"? i.e. Which version did you see? Version 1 or 2?

Comment: This happens only on some posts: [System claims I'm editing the question while I'm only adding a tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350320/system-claims-im-editing-the-question-while-im-only-adding-a-tag)