# Automatic edits prevent users from edit when retagging only

Tags: bug, tags, suggested-edits, markdown, automatic-edits

Usually it is possible to add a missing tag to a question without editing the question.

However, while editing **some** questions, the editor makes invisible changes automatically, as for example in version 3 here: https://superuser.com/posts/1545938/revisions
This might be due to the CommonMark migration, as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350320/system-claims-im-editing-the-question-while-im-only-adding-a-tag#comment1172792_350322).

Such invisible changes cause the error "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?" and thus prevent users below 2k reputation from adding tags to **only those** answers.

I'm **not** asking [how to trick the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters). I'm reporting a bug, where the site doesn't behave as intended (i.e. doesn't allow to add tags without editing the question) on **some** questions.

Comment: You can get round this restriction by earning 2k rep on the site.

Comment: Post a comment to the author suggesting they add the tag.

Comment: On Meta downvotes are like confetti, they're never alone, try not to to take it personally. Everyone gets downvotes when they post a question on meta that just needed a little research, even when that research was provided.

Comment: I don't understand it either. Even after researching and providing a solution to this problem, I still don't fully understand what happens. It might not be a bug but it's certainly unusual.

Comment: ^ This question is answered in that linked post's section *I'm not modifying the post body, but I'm still receiving an error about needing to change six characters. What gives?*. (@Glorfindel)

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog yeah, [I thought I recognized the issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303041/295232). However, this is a very recent post (two months old), so perhaps it's worth looking into by the developers to what extent CommonMark plays a role in this and whether they need to fix anything.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, this *is* possible, but it might be that the editor automatically strips one or two characters from the question body and interprets this as a change. If you link to the post we can be sure. Most of the times, you can improve something else in the post, or perhaps substitute a word with a synonym and indicate you did this only because of the error message you got.

I just hit the 'edit' link and the 'Save Edits' button and *some* changes were applied: see the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1545938/revisions). I suspect the [CommonMark migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/295232) is to blame. Even the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#ids=1545938&filter=!9_bDDlt%293&site=superuser&run=true) doesn't tell me the difference between the two revisions.

Comment: Here's the question: https://superuser.com/questions/1545938/duplicate-keys-microsoft-keyboard-layout-creator What does the editor do exactly?

Comment: @root I have no idea, but I just hit the 'edit' link and the 'Save Edits' button and *some* changes were applied: https://superuser.com/posts/1545938/revisions. I suspect the CommonMark migration is to blame. You can go ahead and make the suggested edit now.

Comment: If you compare rivisions side by side, the site tells you 3 identical lines are skipped. Perhaps turn thins into a bugreport @Glorfindel regarding the commonmark Migration?